# Is it true that if I have 4GB RAM - Red Hat automatically installs a PAE kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, redhat-enterprise-linux

And if so, is there a way to "downgrade" to the regular kernel?

Comment: Why would you want to downgrade? Performance is really not an issue.

Comment: I am using an encryption software which isn't compatible with a PAE kernel.

Comment: I wouldn't trust encryption software with an obviously incompetent implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no issue having several kernels installed. In fact, to my knowledge it is standard practice to install newer kernel versions alongside the old versions, instead of overwriting the old kernel while it is running and thus risking ending up with a non-functioning system after next reboot.

One can see the application in always keeping a verified working kernel in place.